# KOTLIN How to extend superclass of existing class

Tags: kotlin

I have a helper class to get network updates. When I try to create secondary constructor it throws an error.

Based on the documentation for kotlin I need to extend the super class. But I get the same error.

As per the documentation, `ConnectivityManager` does not have a constructor.

I get this error:

> `Supertype initialization is impossible without primary constructor`

My helper class:

```
class InternetConnectivityHelper : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    constructor(context: Context, internetStatusChangedListener: InternetStatusChangedListener): super(){

    }
}
```

I also tried the following based on one of the stackoverflow answers:

```
class InternetConnectivityHelper : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    constructor(context: Context, internetStatusChangedListener: InternetStatusChangedListener): this(){

    }
}
```

Comment: You can try Kotlin Extensions to extend the original class by adding your functionalities  to it . https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/extensions-in-kotlin-197bced14141

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

Add **`parentheses`** with class name for `primary constructor`.

```
class InternetConnectivityHelper() : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    constructor(context: Context, internetStatusChangedListener: InternetStatusChangedListener): this(){

    }
}
```

OR

Remove **`parentheses`** from the class name to define `secondary constructor` without defining the `primary constructor`.

```
class InternetConnectivityHelper : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {

    constructor(context: Context, internetStatusChangedListener: InternetStatusChangedListener): super(){

    }
}
```